# FullCalendar not displaying in wanted timezone

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar

Using `fullCalendar` I am not able to get it to display in a different timezone.  I am in pacific timezone, but I want to see the events as if I was on New York.  I have also tried to pass the dates in with the offset (`2014-11-20T13:33:00-0800`). No matter what, they display as pacific time zone.  What am I doing wrong?

```php
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dt = "2014-11-20";
    var tz = "America/New_York";
    //Call the fullCallendar method. You can replace the '#calendar' with the ID of the dom element where you want the calendar to go. 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            //left: 'prev,next today',
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
            //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        defaultDate: dt,
        timezone: tz,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        allDaySlot: false,
        events: [

        //At run time, this APEX Repeat will reneder the array elements for the events array
        {
            title: "New Photo Shoot",
            start: '2014-11-20T13:27:00',
            end: '2014-11-20T14:27:00',
            url: '',
            allDay: false,
            className: 'event-personal'
        }, {
            title: "GMB/Calendar Test 4 - Initial Photo Shoot",
            start: '2014-11-20T11:00:00',
            end: '2014-11-20T13:00:00',
            url: '/00UJ00000081xpZMAQ',
            allDay: false,
            className: 'event-birthday'
        }, {
            title: "GMB/Calendar Test 4 - Initial Photo Shoot",
            start: '2014-11-20T10:36:00',
            end: '2014-11-20T12:36:00',
            url: '/00UJ00000081xptMAA',
            allDay: false,
            className: 'event-birthday'
        }, ]
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't see anything strange. What returns if you lunch this at the console? '$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.timezone' ?

Comment: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.timezone
"America/New_York"
@MarioLevrero   It appears that the timezone is set correctly, but an event that should be at 2pm America/New_York time is displaying at 11am (pst).

Comment: Did you get this fixed? @BBastien